# How can i get some packages in deb files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

im wondering if is possible to get the following packages in a deb files

asciidoc autoconf avahi-daemon bison build-essential ccache clang clang-3.7 cmake docbook-website emacs flex freeglut3 freeglut3:i386 g++-multilib gcc-5-base gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-multilib git libc6 libc6-dev libc6-dev:i386 libc6:i386 libcaca0 libcaca0:i386 libdrm2 libdrm2:i386 libedit-dev libegl1-mesa

this is because every day i need to install it in a different workstation and those packages takes a long time to download it, it would be great if i can get in a deb file to saved in a hard drive and be able to install every day in my workstations

btw my os is ubuntu 16.04

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --download-only install asciidoc autoconf avahi-daemon bison build-essential ccache clang clang-3.7 cmake docbook-website emacs flex freeglut3 freeglut3:i386 g++-multilib gcc-5-base gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-multilib git libc6 libc6-dev libc6-dev:i386 libc6:i386 libcaca0 libcaca0:i386 libdrm2 libdrm2:i386 libedit-dev libegl1-mesa
```

All packages with dependencies would be in  /var/cache/apt/archives

Now in other systems, you can use:

```
dpkg -i path/to/packages/*.deb
```

Or you can put these in  /var/cache/apt/archives folder of other systems and when you run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --download-only install asciidoc autoconf avahi-daemon bison build-essential ccache clang clang-3.7 cmake docbook-website emacs flex freeglut3 freeglut3:i386 g++-multilib gcc-5-base gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-multilib git libc6 libc6-dev libc6-dev:i386 libc6:i386 libcaca0 libcaca0:i386 libdrm2 libdrm2:i386 libedit-dev libegl1-mesa
```

You shouldn't get any download unless there have been an update.

Comment: thanks  a lot, let me try it :)

Comment: @shaveax If you face any issue, comment here.

Comment: I also added one more option. If this answer work, then please accept.